# There are $n$ types of element. $i^{th}$ of them appears $f_i$ times. Number of ways to take $r$ element from them.

Tags: combinatorics

> There are $n$ types of element. $i^{th}$ of them appears $f_i$ times. For a given $r$, in how many ways you can take $r$ elements from them?
>   Example: Suppose there are 3 types of element and $f_1 = 0, f_2 = 2, f_3 = 2$. or you can say the set is $\{2,2,3,3\}$. For $r=2$ the answer is $3$. You can take $\{2,2\}, \{2,3\}, \{3,3\}$.

If the question ask about just number of permutation then I can solve it. Total number of elements is $\sum_{i=1}^{n}f_i$ so answer is $$\frac{(\sum_{i=1}^{n}f_i)!}{\prod_{i=1}^{n} f_i!}$$
But how to solve this problem? Where I need to take $r$ elements from them? I am looking for a general formula / method.

Comment: Well this is equivalent to $|\{(a_1,\cdots ,a_n):\sum _{i=1}^na_i=r\wedge a_i\leq f_i\}|$ which can be done by inclusion exclusion.